# Error #1009 with removeChild on Event.target

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events

```
private function bubbleFlury()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < fluryAmount; i++)
        {
            fluryBubble = this.addChild(new bubble());
            fluryBubble.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fluryDisplace);
            fluryBubble.yspeed = randomRange(5, 10);

            with (fluryBubble)
            {
                x = Math.random() * sWidth;
                y = randomRange(sHeight, (sHeight+sHeight));
                width = height = 1 + Math.random() * 60;
            }
        }

        function fluryDisplace(e:Event):void
        {
            e.target.y -=  e.target.yspeed;

            if (e.target.y <= 0 - e.target.height)
            {
                var t:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(e.target);
                t.parent.removeChild(t)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the function I can't figure out:

```
function fluryDisplace(e:Event):void
    {
        e.target.y -=  e.target.yspeed;

        if (e.target.y <= 0 - e.target.height)
        {
            var t:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(e.target);
            t.parent.removeChild(t)
        }
    }
```

This throws

Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

I'm so confused for some reason.

Comment: One quick tip: don't add a listener to every bubble. It is much better to have ONE game loop that updates your bubbles. Add them to an Array or a Vector at creation and loop through the list on each update.

Comment: have you traced `t.parent`? or t? if not try `e.target as DisplayObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the `removeChild()`, make sure to also **remove the EnterFrame Event listener**:

```
function fluryDisplace(e:Event):void
{
    e.target.y -=  e.target.yspeed;

    if (e.target.y <= 0 - e.target.height)
    {
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fluryDisplace);

        var t:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(e.target);
        t.parent.removeChild(t);

    }
}
```

Otherwise, the event keeps firing on and on but the DisplayObject doesn't have a `parent` anymore and thus `t.parent` is null (and you get the feared `1009 Error`).

Hope my explanation wasn't too confusing. Also, I advice to read carefully what Mattias writes in his comment and try not to add more than ONE EnterFrame listener, as they are very costly performance wise.

Comment: Nice one. I removed my answer when I realised that `Event.target` is an `Object`.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much for making sense of this. I'm not sure how I go about having one enterframe for all the particles.

Comment: Mattias' explanation covered it quite well; set just one enterframe listener (outside of the foor loop), and add the particles to a vector or array upon creation. On the EnterFrame event listener, loop through all the particles inside the vector/array and update them. Good luck! and if the code gives you any trouble, you know where to ask ;)